# codeigniter database error add

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

> Table 'gtv.1tbpost' doesn't exist
>
> INSERT INTO `1tbpost` (`post_title`) VALUES ('')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/1/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691
>
> ---

**database.php**
/

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'gtv',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '1',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

---

**model:**

```
public function add(){
            $data=array(

            'post_title'=>$this->input->post('title'),

            );
        $this->db->insert('tbpost',$data);
        }
```

**controller:**

```
   public function add_validate(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|regex_match[/^[A-Za-z0-9 .]+$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s is required.');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'minimum characters for %s is %s');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('regex_match', '%s is not in the correct format');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            if($this->input->post('add') == "post"){
                $this->gtvmod->add();
            }else if($this->input->post('add') == "save"){
                $this->index();
            }else if($this->input->post('add') == "cancel"){
                $this->index();
            }else{
                $this->index();
            }

        }else{
            if($this->input->post('add') == "post"){
                $this->add();//punta model
            }else if($this->input->post('add') == "save"){
                $this->index();//punta model
            }else if($this->input->post('add') == "cancel"){
                $this->index();//punta model
            }else{
                $this->index();//punta model
            }
        }
    }
```

---

problem I specify that my table is 'tbpost' but the error says that I insert into table '1tbpost' .

Comment: are you doing other successful inserts elsewhere in the app?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just starting codeigniter

Comment: fine...just curious if you have any other database inserts working or selects even for that matter. Something is mis-configured somewhere...not sure where though

Comment: Show us your /application/config/database.php content

Comment: table name seems different in the error message and insert query

Answer (score 0):

In your database.php you have `'dbprefix' => '1',` and you need to change it to `'dbprefix' => '',`

Answer (score 0):

you have called a not existing table in your database so check the table names that you have called.

if you have form validation library check the rules the table's name is maybe hidden there haha

relax and enjoy programming !